# Updating Parquet datasets where the schema changes overtime

Tags: pandas, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a single parquet file that I have been incrementally been building every day for several months.  The file size is around 1.1GB now and when read into memory it approaches my PCs memory limit.  So, I would like to split it up into several files base on the year and month combination (i.e. `Data_YYYYMM.parquet.snappy`) that will all be in a directory.

My current process reads in the daily csv that I need to append, reads in the historical parquet file with pyarrow and converts to pandas, concats the new and historical data in pandas (`pd.concat([df_daily_csv, df_historical_parquet])`) and then writes back to a single parquet file.  Every few weeks the schema of the data can change (i.e. a new column).  With my current method this is not an issue since the concat in pandas can handle the different schemas and I overwriting it each time.

By switching to this new setup I am worried about having inconsistent schemas between months and then being unable to read in data over multiple months. I have tried this already and gotten errors due to non matching schemas.  I thought might be able to specify this with the schema parameter in `pyarrow.parquet.Dataset`.  From the doc it looks like it takes a type of `pyarrow.parquet.Schema`.  When I try using this I get `AttributeError: module 'pyarrow.parquet' has no attribute 'Schema'`.  I also tried taking the schema of a pyarrow Table (`table.schema`) and passing that to the schema parameter but got an error msg (sry I forget error right now and cant connect workstation right now so cant reproduce error - I will update with this info when I can).

I've seen some mention of schema normalization in the context of the broader Arrow/Datasets project but I'm not sure if my use case fits what that covers and also the Datasets feature is experimental so I dont want to use it in production.

I feel like this is a pretty common use case and I wonder if I am missing something or if parquet isn't meant for schema changes over time like I'm experiencing.  I've considered investigating the schema of the new file and comparing vs historical and then if there is change deserializing, updating schema, and reserializing every file in the dataset but I'm really hoping to avoid that.

So my questions are:

1. Will using a pyarrow parquet Dataset (or something else in the pyarrow API) allow me to read in all of the data in multiple parquet files even if the schema is different?  To be specific, my expectation is that the new column would be appended and the values prior to when this column were available would be null). If so, how do you do this?
2. If the answer to 1 is no, is there another method or library for handling this?

Some resources I've been going through.

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-2659

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.html#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset

Comment: Find a solution to this? I am looking for something similar.